# how to count the number of integers input by the user

Tags: input, int, variable-length

i have to make a program that reads an arbitrarily long integer input from the user and finds the sum of the digits. i was thinking about making the program do a loop until the integer count is zero and adding up the sum of the numbers the user typed in. but im not sure how to write that since im a beginner at java. this is what i got from my try at it

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class sumofnumberstest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 int data;
 int sum = 0;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print( "Enter an integer ): ");
 data = input.nextInt();
 int length = data.length
 do {
data %10;
 sum += data;
 } while (data.length >=0 & = 100000000000000000000000000000 );

 System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
 }
 }
```

Comment: errors: Syntax error on token "do", invalid AssignmentOperator, Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s), Syntax error on token "}", delete this token, Syntax error on token "=", delete this token

Answer (score 0):

your question is similar to a previously asked question. Take a look here  -> [How to read each individual digit of a number in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859633/how-to-read-each-individual-digit-of-a-number-in-java)

Here's a simple implementation of what you're trying to do:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861955/6913557